# CSS cursor:cell not working in safari browser

Tags: html, css

CSS **cursor:cell** property not working safari browser. i have created simple div tag and set cursor as cell, but it is not working in **safari browser**.

```css
#cursor{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  cursor:cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor"></div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Safari 8. Which version are you using?

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: Works fine for me.. maybe safari is outdated..?

Comment: my safari version is 5.1.7.

Comment: Safari *5.1.7* is the last version of Safari for Windows. It's outdated, not supported and maintained anymore and it's highly recommended to use another browser instead. Also, you don't have to test your sites in this old version.

Comment: Years and years since safari for windows is unsupported. Don't make developments for this safari. Real safari users are from Mac and iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor: cell;` isn't supported in your version of Safari.

See here - http://caniuse.com/#search=cursor